# What exactly the expression "make an argument" means?

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

I wonder what exactly the expression "make an argument" means on this phrase: "Machiavelli makes the argument that in a strictly military sense a fortress is invariably a mistake."

I'm not sure if it is a idiomatic expression. Does it mean that Machiavelli **advocates** that this point is a mistake, or that he **does not advocate** this idea?

Comment: i'm talking about the whole expression: "make an argument". I thought it would be an idiomatic expression (different meaning from his literal translation), in which case a dictionary couldn't help me.

Comment: I don't see that it's idiomatic.  "Make an argument" simply means "argue (for) something".  If the person arguing does not advocate an idea, then you would explicitly say "make an argument **against** something", but in this it's no different from "to argue".  *Machiavelli **argues** that in the strictly military sense a fortress is a mistake.*

Answer (score 1):

In this context "makes an argument" means exactly the same as "puts a case": he presents the reasons why he thinks that a fortress is a mistake when considered in a simply military sense.

It does not imply that there is a disagreement with any particular person.